# Do you have to know the image file type before uploading to Firebase Storage?

Tags: image, flutter, firebase-storage

When adding an image file from a device that is retrieved by the user to firebase cloud storage, would it be okay to append `.jpg`, `.png`, or `.webp` to the filename?

For example,

```
storageReference.child('images/example.jpg').putFile(file)
```

or

```
storageReference.child('images/example.png').putFile(file)
```

I've been doing this in the past with no problems, but it doesn't feel right.
Would I have to retrieve the file type and add the appropriate extension?

I would want all the images in the firebase storage to have the same file extension, but I am not sure if getting different file types from [ImagePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and adding a uniform extension is a proper way to save an image?

Creating a flutter app...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify a type. If you specify a specific file ending like .png or .jpg, firebase storage will override the auto-detected type. Take a look at the firebase storage docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata). It goes into more depth, but bottom-line answer is if you specify a file type firebase storage will update the initial auto-detected type.

Comment: 2024 - The auto-detect feature is no more: ` If no contentType metadata is specified and the file doesn't have a file extension, Cloud Storage defaults to the type application/octet-stream.`